# Why can I not put an if statement anywhere in my code? I am using swift

Tags: xcode, if-statement, xcode6-beta6

I just started writing a new app in Xcode beta 6 and I need to write an if statement for my code to work but I keep getting the error `Expected declaration` no matter where I put the if statement. 
my code is

```
let randomNumberColorPicker = arc4random_uniform(4) + 1



 if randomNumberColorPicker == 1 {
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
       }
```

What can I do to actually make this work?

Comment: this code looks okay to me. your problem is coming from outside of this code block.  what's above your "`let randomNumberColorPicker`" line?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your code is not in a function. Move your code into viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let randomNumberColorPicker = arc4random_uniform(4) + 1
     if randomNumberColorPicker == 1 {
       println("true")
    }else{
        println("falseMove your code int viewDidLoad")
    }
 }
```